# Mutable class variables and the behavior of super().__init__

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand why my code is behaving the way it is. Basically I've created a parent and child class in two ways. What I'd like to happen is that on each instance that is created for the two classes, the **init** method will update the count of num_of_emps for **each respective** class. So if I have something like:

```py
class Employee:

    num_of_emps = 0

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, division):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.division = division
        Employee.num_of_emps += 1

class Manager(Employee):

    num_of_emps = 0

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, division):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.division = division
        Manager.num_of_emps += 1

emp1 = Employee("Dallas", "Mat", 100000, "Sales")
emp2 = Employee("Mark", "Doe", 50000, "Marketing")
emp3 = Employee("Jane", "Doe", 50000, "Advertisement")
man1 = Manager("Bob", "Ben", 200000, "Marketing")
man2 = Manager("Ryan", "DS", 200000, "Advertisement")

# Employee.num_of_emps returns 3
# Manager.num_of_emps returns 2
```

This is what I want. However, if I add a super.**init**() method rather than hard coding the attributes of the Manager class, something else happens:

```py
class Employee:

    num_of_emps = 0

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, division):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.division = division
        Employee.num_of_emps += 1

class Manager(Employee):

    num_of_emps = 0

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, division):
        super().__init__(first, last, pay, division)
        Manager.num_of_emps += 1

emp1 = Employee("Dallas", "Mat", 100000, "Sales")
emp2 = Employee("Mark", "Doe", 50000, "Marketing")
emp3 = Employee("Jane", "Doe", 50000, "Advertisement")
man1 = Manager("Bob", "Ben", 200000, "Marketing")
man2 = Manager("Ryan", "DS", 200000, "Advertisement")

# Employee.num_of_emps returns 5
# Manager.num_of_emps returns 2
```

What's confusing me is the parent classes' num_of_emps is also getting updated each time a manager instance is being created. I know the super().**init** method is causing this but can someone explain why?

Comment: super().__init__ is calling the method bound to the superclass, in this case it's like calling Employee.__init__, which as you would expect, updates the num_of_emps of the Employee class

Comment: Your class hierarchy says that a Manager is also an Employee. So you have 5 employees and 2 of them are managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because super().**init**() calls the super init method. And in that method you increment the Manager count.  This is a problem with inheritance. A better way to do this might be to segment your classes better.

Additionally two other suggestions were given in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57559437/8964267) that are better structured than the code sample I'm giving to try and show how to compartmentalize your problem as simply as possible.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self):
        # Some stuff
        pass


class Employee(Person):

    counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Some stuff
        Employee.counter += 1
        pass


class Manager(Person):

    counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Some stuff
        Manager.counter += 1
        pass
```

This will avoid triggering the counter attribute on the base class more than once.

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware that super also calls any method bound to the parent's class.

Comment: There are better ways that avoid code duplication, hardcoded class names etc.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, absolutely. But, I was trying to come up with a solution that closely followed their design. I didn't want to do a lesson on OOP that can be found all over the web.

Comment: @EmilianoJordan obviously - given how much ugly / braindead / rube-goldberg-like code we see around here -, "lessons on OOP that can be found all over the web" are either pretty bad or no one cares reading them anymore. OTHO a whole lot of beginners are reading SO - remember that answers posted here are supposed to be of general interest, not only to address the OP's specifics -, so better to promote best practices... Whoever is reading answers here might be the author of some code you'll one day have to maintain, and then you wish they had written much better code. Just my 2 cents ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, fair point. But at what point do you answer the question to the level of people that will be looking for this type of help. And when do you start going over their head and just leave them with a copy pasta solution that they don't actually understand. 

BTW, I edited my answer to link to yours as well.

Answer (score 1):

You already had the answer to the "why" part so I won't come back to it.

For the solution, in your case, just avoiding hardcoding the class name (using `type(self)` instead to get the current instance's class) solves the issue (nb: if you consider that updating  the `Employee` counter is an issue):

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     counter = 0
...     def __init__(self):
...         print("base.__init__")
...         type(self).counter += 1
... 
>>> class Child(Base):
...     pass
... 
>>> c = Child()
base.__init__
>>> Base.counter
0
>>> Child.counter
1
```

A cleaner solution would be to factor out the counter incrementation in a classmethod so you can both have the expected default yet override it if needed, ie:

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     counter = 0
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.inc_counter()
...     @classmethod
...     def inc_counter(cls):
...         cls.counter += 1
... 
>>> class Child(Base):
...     pass
... 
>>> c = Child()
>>> Child.counter
1
>>> Base.counter
0
```